# Show tables based on clicking a TextBox

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I wanted to know if there is a possibility to have a Textbox on a report which says something like "SHOW TABLES". When clicked the tables in the report should show.

My report contains tables and Charts. I want to be able to show the charts but not the tables. I should be able to show the tables only when the user clicks on "SHOW TABLES"

It should not rerun the report once we click the TextBox.

Comment: It would help if you tell us what you've tried so far, and where you got stuck. Share your research with us.

Comment: I have tried to this =IIF(ReportItems!Textbox36.Value<> "", True,False) in the visibility of the Tablix.But did not help. I have  also tried to define the Action in the Textbox properties of the box, but it reloads into a new report.

Comment: I know the above expression is wrong, but My question is something like that doable without having to go to a new report alltogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "rerun the report".

You can set the **ToggleItem** property of the tables you want to hide to the name of your *Show Tables* textbox.

Set the initial visibilty of the tables to be hidden. Clicking the *Show Tables* textbox will show the tables. Clicking on the textbox will hide them again.

In my testing, the report will re-render, but it will *not* load its DataSets again. So there will be some processing to update the report appearance but it's more lightweight than reloading a report from scratch.

It may not fit your needs perfectly but might be worth investigating.

Comment: Ohh man the Toggle item.Thanks Ian, your answers have #ALWAYS  been helpful.Thank a ton.

Answer (score 1):

right click on the report  "'tablix properties"

[image]
In Display can be toggled by this report item, from the drop-down box, type or select the name of a text box in the report in which to display a toggle image; for example, Textbox1.

In the following image, the table is configured to enable users to expand and collapse it. The display of the table is toggled by the Products Table text box.

5.To test the toggle, run the report and click the text box with the toggle image. The report display refreshes to show report items with their toggled visibility.

[image]